# How to pick the HQ you want in skirmish mode?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

I have the game including "Jupiter" expansion (it was auto included), which means I have 6 HQs available, but when I start a skirmish mode, I can see only 4 HQs.

Is there a way to cyle through the 6 HQs ? or is there a way to disable Jupiter expansion so I can train only on the 4 basic HQs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default skirmish settings give players 4 random HQs out of the 6. Each player gets the same options.

You can force all 6 to be available by selecting Include All HQs from the custom game rules.

[image: The option is highlighted]